# hector-mapping Lookup would require extrapolation into the future

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i try to run hector-slam on the asctec pelican. But when i launch hector-mapping i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1230818054.341736259]: Transform failed during publishing of map_odom transform: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1230818053.694549500 but the latest data is at time 1230818053.195532500, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/nav]
```

If i am right, that error means that my tf data is to old so it is not used or ?
I have tried to set the publish rate of tf higher (up to 1000Hz), but the error keeps. I also have make sure that i do not use the sim time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67446/hector-mapping---lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EwingKang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19209/ewingkang/) on 2014-07-05**:
Hi, did you solve the problem? I've got the same problem here which prohibits me from keep going. Couldn't find any related support .Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I faced this problem, too. And I solved this problem through this method.
In the hectormapping launch file, I added the line below:

Then everything is OK. I am under the environment: ROS Hydro+turtlebot2

So I guess the problem is caused by some parameters of the mobe_base.launch.xml

---

Originally posted by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) with karma: 130 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0